# print list without repetitive items

Tags: python

Is it possible to print a list like a table but skip over parts of the data columns that are identical?

For example, my list:

```
l = [('name1','species','description','country','n/a'),
     ('name1','species','description','country','plasmid1'),
     ('name1','species','description','country','plasmid2')]


for l in list_description:
    print '\t'.join(l)
```

What I get:

```
name1 species description country n/a
name1 species description country plasmid1
name1 species description country plasmid2
```

What I hope to get:

```
name1 species description country n/a
                                  plasmid1
                                  plasmid2
```

If it is not possible using table, I can consider to use a dictionary, too.

Comment: eliminating the...?

Comment: Is there something like `name2, species, ..., plasmid37` in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adam's solution is good, but I also want to supply one that uses, as you suggested, a dictionary. That way you have some more flexibility in your data parsing, don't need to care about ordering, and the appending operation is a bit simpler as well:

```
l = [('name1','species','description','country','n/a'),
     ('name1','species','description','country','plasmid1'),
     ('name1','species','description','country','plasmid2')]

d = {}
for line in l:
  key, val = ' '.join(line[:-1]), line[-1]
  if key in d:
    d[key] += '\n' + ' '*(len(key)+1) + val
  else:
    d[key] = val

for key, val in d.items():
  print("{} {}".format(key, val))
```

Output:

```
name1 species description country n/a
                                  plasmid1
                                  plasmid2
```

Answer (score 3):

you can keep track of the last line printed, compare the two, then replace identical elements with an equivalent number of spaces.

```
import itertools

l = [('name1','species','description','country','n/a'),
     ('name1','species','description','country','plasmid1'),
     ('name1','species','description','country','plasmid2')]

last_line = []
for ll in l:
    line = [" "*len(el_l) if el_l == el_last else el_l
            for el_l, el_last in itertools.zip_longest(ll, last_line, fillvalue=None)]
    last_line = ll
    print("\t".join(line))
```

Comment: There is a side effect to this interesting solution. If for instance `country` is the same for `name 1`and `name2`, only country is removed in the printout for `name2`.

Comment: @Piinthesky I would assume that was the expected functionality.

Comment: I don't even know, if there is a `name2`. The OP is remarkably silent, given all these beautiful suggestions. But if there are more entries, then `country2` shouldn't disappear, just because it is accidentally the same as `country1`. Yours is nonetheless the best solution in terms of approach and result - the accepted one changes the order of list elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a list comprehension, but it is quite convoluted:

```
l = [('name1','species','description','country','n/a'),
     ('name1','species','description','country','plasmid1'),
     ('name1','species','description','country','plasmid2')]

print ' '.join([l[j][i]+"\n"*int(i==len(l[j])-1) if len(set([k[i] for k in l])) == len(l) or j==0 else ' '*len([k[i] for k in l][0]) for j in range(len(l)) for i in range(len(l[j]))])
```

---

```
name1 species description country n/a
                                   plasmid1
                                   plasmid2

>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If a `tuple` is at index `0` in the `list_description`, print all of the `tuple` elements separated by a white space. Else, print white space characters plus the item at index `-1` in each `tuple`.

```
list_description = [('name1','species','description','country','n/a'),
                    ('name1','species','description','country','plasmid1'),
                    ('name1','species','description','country','plasmid2')]

lengths = sum(len(item) for item in list_description[0])

for i, tup in enumerate(list_description):    
    if i == 0:
        print(' '.join(tup[:-1]) + ' ' + tup[-1])        
    else:
        print(' ' * lengths + ' ' + tup[-1])

name1 species description country n/a
                                  plasmid1
                                  plasmid2
>>>
```